# postgres csv date null import error

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I am importing data into a Postgres database. The table I am importing to includes a couple of columns with dates.

The CSV file I am uploading, however, has empty values for some of the date fields.

The table looks like this:

```
dot_number bigint,
legal_name character varying,
dba_name character varying,
carrier_operation character varying,
hm_flag character varying,
pc_flag character varying,
...
mcs150_date date,
mcs150_mileage bigint,
```

The data looks like this:

```
1000045,"GLENN M HINES","","C","N","N","317 BURNT BROW RD","HAMMOND","ME","04730","US","317 BURNT BROW RD","HAMMOND","ME","04730","US","(207) 532-4141","","","19-NOV-13","20000","2012","23-JAN-02","ME","1","2"
1000050,"ROGER L BUNCH","","C","N","N","108 ST CHARLES CT","GLASGOW","KY","42141","US","108 ST CHARLES CT","GLASGOW","KY","42141","US","(270) 651-3940","","","","72000","2001","23-JAN-02","KY","1","1"
```

I have tried doing this:

```
COPY CC FROM 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\FMCSA Data\FMCSA_CENSUS1_2016Sep.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER NULL '';
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "" CONTEXT:  COPY cc, line
>   24, column mcs150_date: ""
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "" SQL state: 22007
>   Context: COPY cc, line 24, column mcs150_date: ""

This is probably pretty simple, but none of the solutions I've found online did not work.

Comment: What does your data look like? I assume it includes quotes as text-qualifiers, correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Here's the first record:

1000004,"RAY TRUCKING LLC","A","N","N","WARWICK","GA","31796","US","01-JUL-16","83000","22-JAN-02","GA","1","1"

mcs150_date is the last date field.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the `QUOTE` character so that `""` would be interpreted as `NULL`, like so:

```
COPY CC FROM 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\FMCSA Data\FMCSA_CENSUS1_2016Sep.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER QUOTE '"' NULL '';
```

`QUOTE '"'` was the addition.

Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: Thanks. But I got the same error message. Maybe the table isn't set up correctly? I'm not sure.

Comment: Possibly, update your post to include your table definition as well as a few lines of your data, if possible.

Comment: I added it above.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up importing as text and then altering the tables according to the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Just for any future reference.

Docs:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

says,

> **NULL**
>
> Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N
>   (backslash-N) in text format, and **an unquoted empty string in CSV
>   format**. You might prefer an empty string even in text format for
>   cases where you don't want to distinguish nulls from empty strings.
>   This option is not allowed when using binary format.

so remove the quote on the empty string to obtain an NULL value on these empty date values.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, the issue here was probably the date format of the *not-null* date values.  It's common for an MS Excel file saved to CSV to have that format, `01-JUL-16`, but PostgreSQL will not know what to do with it unless you've first converted it to one of the standard date formats[1].  But PostgreSQL won't be able to accept that format "out of the box" when doing a COPY, because it'll be presented with a date string that doesn't match one of the format masks that it can handle by default.

That, AND the null handling for null date values.

[1] (and perhaps dealt with the consequences of having a 2-digit year upfront, particularly that years prior to 1969 will be interpreted as 20xx).