# Invalid input syntax for type uuid: "" or "null" in PosgreSQL copy command

Tags: postgresql, csv, database-backups

I've made csv-backup from SELECT query and now trying to import it back to the database. But i am getting this error:

```sql
COPY doc FROM '/tmp/doc.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;


ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "null"
```

As you can see, i have NULL as `"null"` in my file.

This happens on the optional field which was empty before.

I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40428667/8443131

But it is not working for me:

```sql
COPY doc FROM '/tmp/doc.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER QUOTE '"null"' NULL '';

ERROR:  COPY quote must be a single one-byte character
```

How do i import this file?

**UPD**: I tried to replace nulls with empty quotes.

Command tried:

```sql
COPY doc FROM '/tmp/null.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER QUOTE '"' NULL '';

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: ""
```

Short version of file:

```
"id","removed","modified_at","root_id","parent_id","acl","properties","data","file_meta"
"f6a16ff7-4a31-11eb-be7b-8344edc8f36b","false","2021-01-04 00:00:12.347988","","","IS_PUBLIC","","",""
"2fdd0b8b-4a70-11eb-99fd-ad786a821574","false","2021-01-04 00:00:06.87298","","","IS_PUBLIC","","",""
"2c6d5fd1-4a70-11eb-99fd-ad786a821574","false","2021-01-04 00:00:07.536212","","","IS_PUBLIC","","",""
"fd645c21-4a6f-11eb-99fd-ad786a821574","false","2021-01-04 00:00:11.892367","","","IS_PUBLIC","","",""
"35c1fc53-4a70-11eb-99fd-ad786a821574","false","2021-01-04 00:00:05.517109","","","IS_PUBLIC","","",""
"35d165a4-4a70-11eb-99fd-ad786a821574","false","2021-01-04 00:00:01.72546","","","IS_PUBLIC","","",""
"fd40806d-4a6f-11eb-99fd-ad786a821574","false","2021-01-04 00:00:09.173726","","","IS_PUBLIC","","",""
"30ba4b45-4a70-11eb-99fd-ad786a821574","false","2021-01-04 00:00:04.655073","","","IS_PUBLIC","","",""
```

Table creation:

```sql
-- Dumped from database version 13.0 (Debian 13.0-1.pgdg100+1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.0 (Debian 13.0-1.pgdg100+1)



CREATE TABLE public.doc (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    removed boolean,
    modified_at timestamp without time zone,
    root_id uuid,
    parent_id uuid,
    acl jsonb,
    properties jsonb,
    data jsonb,
    file_meta jsonb
);



ALTER TABLE ONLY public.doc
    ADD CONSTRAINT doc_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.doc
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_document_entity FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES public.main_table(id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.doc
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_document_parent FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES public.doc(id);
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, now i got it. But i have quote character in my null definition and it fails: `COPY doc FROM '/tmp/doc.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER NULL '"null"' QUOTE '"'`. If i remove the quotes from `"null"` it fails as before. My other data such as uuids is in the quotes `""` too.

Comment: I tried `CSV HEADER NULL 'null' QUOTE '"'` but it says `invalid input syntax for type uuid: "null"` again

Comment: `COPY doc FROM program 'sed -e ''s/""//g'' /tmp/null.csv' WITH (DELIMITER ',', FORMAT CSV, HEADER, QUOTE '"', NULL '');`

Comment: @Abelisto something moved. Now it is error with jsonb: ```ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "IS_PUBLIC" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: IS_PUBLIC
COPY document_meta, line 2, column acl: "IS_PUBLIC"```. But i guess i can escape it with `{}` or something

Comment: Yes, `IS_PUBLIC` is not a valid JSON definitelly, but this is another story.

Comment: Note that the previous `sed` command replaces any occurances of `""`. The actual command should be as something as `sed -e 's/^""//g' -e 's/,""$/,/g' -e 's/,"",/,,/g'`

Comment: Thank you for help. "IS_PUBLIC" was uploaded by the app and i have more of this lines in the table. But i guess i'll just put `{}` here and then update this lines from the app.

Answer (score 6):

I reproduced your case with the following, assuming the second column is a `boolean` and the 3rd a `timestamp`

```
create table test (col1 varchar, col2 boolean, col3 timestamp, col4 varchar, col5 varchar, col6 varchar, col7 varchar, col8 varchar, col9 varchar)                                  ;
```

if now i use

```
copy test from STDIN delimiter ',' CSV QUOTE '"' NULL 'null';
```

and pass the string you mentioned

```
"f6a16ff7-4a31-11eb-be7b-8344edc8f36b","false","2021-01-04 00:00:12.347988","null","null","IS_PUBLIC","null","null","null"
```

The data is parsed correctly

```
COPY 1
```

and the output from the table looks correct.

```
defaultdb=> select * from test;
                 col1                 | col2 |            col3            | col4 | col5 |   col6    | col7 | col8 | col9 
--------------------------------------+------+----------------------------+------+------+-----------+------+------+------
 f6a16ff7-4a31-11eb-be7b-8344edc8f36b | f    | 2021-01-04 00:00:12.347988 | null | null | IS_PUBLIC | null | null | null
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is basically the query from the link. I tried it but nothing changed. I've added table query and example lines from file. I also tried to change nulls to "" as it was in linked question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can load this file with `COPY`, since `"null"` is quoted with double quotes and consequently cannot be used as NULL placeholder – it is always interpreted as string.

The best you can do is to load the file into a table where the respective columns are defined as `text`, then do something like

```
ALTER TABLE doc ALTER uuidcol TYPE uuid USING CAST(nullif(uuidcol, 'null') AS uuid);
```

Comment: I also tried to change it to "" or "^" as in linked question but still no luck

Comment: What do you mean by that comment? Is there a problem with my answer?

Comment: I was trying to say that i tried to change this file to upload it. I can't make another table since there is data in current table.

Comment: If you remove the double quotes, it will work with `NULL 'null'`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though @Abelisto command was working i still wasn't be able to upload some jsonb lines.

But i also had an .json alternative of my file like this:

```json
[
    {
        "c0": "f6a16ff7-4a31-11eb-be7b-8344edc8f36b",
        "c1": false,
        "c2": "2021-01-04 00:00:12.347988",
        "c3": null,
        "c4": null,
        "c5": "IS_PUBLIC",
        "c6": null,
        "c7": null,
        "c8": null
    },
    ...
]
```

So i end up in writing this python script which worked for me:

```py
import json
import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime
import uuid


connection = psycopg2.connect(user="admin",
                              password="admin",
                              host="127.0.0.1",
                              port="5432",
                              database="postgres")
cursor = connection.cursor()


def insertLine(line):

    id = uuid.UUID(line['c0']).hex

    removed = bool(line['c1'])

    modified_at = datetime.strptime(line['c2'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

    root_id = uuid.UUID(line['c3']).hex if line['c3'] else None
    parent_id = uuid.UUID(line['c4']).hex if line['c4'] else None

    acl = json.dumps(line['c5']) if line['c5'] else None

    properties = json.dumps(line['c6']) if line['c6'] else None
    data = json.dumps(line['c7']) if line['c7'] else None
    file_meta = json.dumps(line['c8']) if line['c8'] else None

    record_to_insert = (id, removed, modified_at, root_id,
                        parent_id, acl, properties, data, file_meta)

    try:
        postgres_insert_query = """INSERT INTO doc (id, removed, modified_at, root_id, parent_id, acl, properties, data, file_meta) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        
        cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)

        connection.commit()
        count = cursor.rowcount


    except psycopg2.Error as error:
        print("ERROR:" + str(error))


file = 'table.json'

with open(file) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data:
        insertLine(p)


if connection:
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

So i guess it is just bad practice to backup jsonb fields in csv.